# Program does unexpectedly finish and complications with connection to local Bluetooth address

Tags: qt, bluetooth

I am trying to connect to local Bluetooth address:

```
void Widget::connect_to_local_Bluetooth( )
{

    qDebug()<<"trying to connect"<<endl;
     QBluetoothAddress address("00:1A:7D:DA:71:15");
    qDebug()<<address.toString()<<endl;
    if(socket.state() != QBluetoothSocket::UnconnectedState)
   {
        qDebug()<<"socket.state"<<endl;
       if(address != socket.peerAddress())//???
       {
            qDebug()<<"socket.peeradress"<<endl;
           socket.disconnectFromService();
           socket.connectToService(address, QBluetoothUuid(QBluetoothUuid::SerialPort));
       }
       //else
         //  emit connected();
   }
   else{
         qDebug()<<"else case"<<endl;
       socket.connectToService(address, QBluetoothUuid(QBluetoothUuid::SerialPort));
    }
}
```

When I compile and run this, it all is working, but when this SLOT is called program writes:

trying to connect

address

else

and then unexpectedly finishes.
Why so? What should I correct here? 
Thank you!

P.S.
When I compile and run it on my Android device it does not interrupt, but I have no idea, is he connected to my Desktop or not. local address of Desktop is 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15

here is message from debugger:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////// bluetooth is powered off
W/ResourceType(15962): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000005
I/View    (15962): Touch down dispatch to org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtSurface{41e7a900 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1024,695 #5}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=175.8283, y[0]=70.87516, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=12082488, downTime=12082488, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8593b50,id:443,api:2,p:15962,c:136) [queue] fps:0.67, dur:3002.75, max:2887.19, min:115.55
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb8593b50,id:443,api:2,p:15962,c:136) [release] fps:0.66, dur:3009.61, max:2887.47, min:122.15
W/ResourceType(15962): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000005
I/View    (15962): Touch up dispatch to org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtSurface{41e7a900 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1024,695 #5}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=175.8283, y[0]=70.87516, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=12082557, downTime=12082488, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:59 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): trying to connect
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962):
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:61 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): "00:1A:7D:DA:71:15"
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962):
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:64 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): socket.state
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962):
D/BluetoothDevice(15962): mAddress: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15


//  ///////////////////////////   bluetooth is on

W/ResourceType(15962): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000006
I/View    (15962): Touch down dispatch to org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtSurface{41dce2d8 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1024,695 #6}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=178.82536, y[0]=70.87516, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=12161746, downTime=12161746, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb85a3680,id:456,api:2,p:15962,c:136) new GraphicBuffer needed
D/GraphicBuffer(15962): create handle(0x6aa44f78) (w:1024, h:695, f:1)
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb85a3680,id:456,api:2,p:15962,c:136) [queue] fps:0.40, dur:5054.98, max:4978.11, min:76.87
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb85a3680,id:456,api:2,p:15962,c:136) [release] fps:0.20, dur:4970.67, max:4970.67, min:4970.67
W/ResourceType(15962): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000006
I/View    (15962): Touch up dispatch to org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtSurface{41dce2d8 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1024,695 #6}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=178.82536, y[0]=70.87516, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=12161842, downTime=12161746, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:59 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): trying to connect
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962):
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:61 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): "00:1A:7D:DA:71:15"
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962):
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:64 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): socket.state
D/libA_for_w8.so(15962):
D/BluetoothDevice(15962): mAddress: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15



/////////////////////////////////////   bluetooth is on too 

W/ResourceType(18110): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000004
I/View    (18110): Touch down dispatch to org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtSurface{4202d638 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1024,695 #4}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=187.81659, y[0]=65.88166, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=12572050, downTime=12572050, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb85bf140,id:496,api:2,p:18110,c:136) new GraphicBuffer needed
D/GraphicBuffer(18110): create handle(0x6c277498) (w:1024, h:695, f:1)
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb85bf140,id:496,api:2,p:18110,c:136) [queue] fps:0.39, dur:5184.50, max:5110.70, min:73.81
I/BufferQueue(  136): [SurfaceView](this:0xb85bf140,id:496,api:2,p:18110,c:136) [release] fps:0.20, dur:5127.71, max:5127.71, min:5127.71
W/ResourceType(18110): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000004
I/View    (18110): Touch up dispatch to org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtSurface{4202d638 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1024,695 #4}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=187.81659, y[0]=65.88166, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=12572146, downTime=12572050, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:59 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): trying to connect
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110):
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:61 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): "00:1A:7D:DA:71:15"
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110):
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:75 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): else
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110):
D/BluetoothAdapter(18110): 1105859416: getState(). Returning 12
D/BluetoothDevice(18110): mAddress: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110): ..\A_for_w8\widget.cpp:80 (void Widget::try_connect_to_local_address()): 
D/libA_for_w8.so(18110):
D/dalvikvm(18110): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x6c857000
W/BluetoothAdapter(18110): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothSocket(18110): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[71]}
D/BluetoothDevice(18110): mAddress: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15
W/System.err(18110): java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
W/System.err(18110):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:505)
W/System.err(18110):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:516)
W/System.err(18110):    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:320)
W/System.err(18110):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
W/libA_for_w8.so(18110): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Falling back to workaround.
W/libA_for_w8.so(18110): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Cannot determine RFCOMM service channel.
D/BluetoothDevice(18110): mAddress: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15
W/libA_for_w8.so(18110): (null):0 ((null)): qt.bluetooth.android: Workaround thread invoked.
D/dalvikvm(18110): threadid=13: bye!
D/dalvikvm(18110): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x6c857000
W/BluetoothAdapter(18110): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
D/BluetoothSocket(18110): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[70]}
D/BluetoothDevice(18110): mAddress: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15
```

To sum up:
1) Why it does not interrupt on Android, but does on Desktop ?
2) How can I understand, is there connection between two my devices ?
3) if doesn't what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You don't need to use `endl` with `qDebug`!

Comment: Have you ran it under a debugger?

Comment: yes, I used debugger mode. I did not know about endl, but anyway it does not seem as the root of the problem

Comment: I just mentioned endl because it's not needed. It has nothing to do with your problem of course. If you run it under the debugger, how do you not know why it crashes? Don't you see the stack trace?

Comment: I see it in application output sorry, so correctly expression is probably: "I run it and when I call slot connect_to_local_bluetooth() it crashes on Desktop but did not on Android"

Comment: You are aware that in Qt Creator you can either Run (^R/⌘R) the program, or Debug (F5 on Win, ⌘Y on OS X) it, right? To know what happens when it crashes, you're supposed to Debug your program, *not* Run it. The debugger will stop it at the moment of the crash and you can then inspect what's going on. Since the crash is likely to be inside of Qt's source code, you should have your own build of Qt, so that you can step into Qt's source and see what's going on.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.
It says:

The inferior stopped because it received a signal from OS.
Signal name: SIGSEGV.
Signal meaning: Segmentation fault.

it crashes on the line socket.connectToService(address, QBluetoothUuid(QBluetoothUuid::SerialPort));